# Test instrumentation process crashes when running in emulator with -no-window

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-espresso, qemu, android-logcat

Our Android Espresso UI tests are able to pass when running on a normal windowed Linux Android emulator, but fail when we run them with the `-no-window -no-audio` flags. We've pulled the Test Orchestrator files and Logcat information but can't seem to find the root of our problem.

We have two UI tests right now that are essentially doing nothing. Removing the second one makes the test pass.

Both work fine as is using Android emulator on Windows (both with and without `-no-window -no-audio`).

#### System specs

- Ubuntu Server - 16.04.4
- SDK Tools - 26.1.1
- Build Tools - 27.0.3
- Android Emulator - 27.2.9
- Android Image - android-27 x86

#### Source

- [MainActivityTest.java](https://github.com/symboxtra/SplitSound-Android/blob/d04024569c688c91cd99edabd43df3a63426d20a/mobile/src/androidTest/java/splitsound/com/splitsound/MainActivityTest.java)
- [SettingsActivityTest.java](https://github.com/symboxtra/SplitSound-Android/blob/d04024569c688c91cd99edabd43df3a63426d20a/mobile/src/androidTest/java/splitsound/com/splitsound/SettingsActivityTest.java)

#### Logs

**/data/data/......./SettingsActivityTest#useAppContext.txt**

```
onError: commandError=true message=null
android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:764)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startInstrumentation(IActivityManager.java:5061)
    at com.android.commands.am.Instrument.run(Instrument.java:419)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:187)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:80)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:54)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:50)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:285)
```

**Logcat output (excerpt of where we think the problem is)**

```
--------- beginning of crash
05-25 02:13:02.182  1629  2688 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xc9d86050 in tid 2688 (RenderThread), pid 1629 (system_server)
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.1.0/OSM1.180201.021/4741582:userdebug/dev-keys'
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   : pid: 1629, tid: 2688, name: RenderThread  >>> system_server <<<
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xc9d86050
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     eax cc0ff1e8  ebx e504cc64  ecx cc64be50  edx 00000000
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     esi 00000058  edi 00000034
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
05-25 02:13:02.830  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     eip c9d86050  ebp cc0ff808  esp cc0ff1ac  flags 00010246
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   : 
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00006050  [anon:libc_malloc:c9d80000]
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000dfd3d  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_swiftshader.so (sw::Renderer::executeTask(int)+189)
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 000dfa07  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_swiftshader.so (sw::Renderer::threadLoop(int)+103)
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 000df98e  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_swiftshader.so (sw::Renderer::threadFunction(void*)+78)
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 000ce064  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_swiftshader.so (sw::Thread::startFunction(void*)+84)
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00071445  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000205db  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
05-25 02:13:03.186  3347  3347 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 0001ec16  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-25 02:13:08.316  2695  2955 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[1]
05-25 02:13:08.316  2695  2955 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 2695
05-25 02:13:08.316  2695  2955 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.320  2820  2820 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.320  2820  2820 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search, PID: 2820
05-25 02:13:08.320  2820  2820 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.329  2695  2695 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.329  2695  2695 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 2695
05-25 02:13:08.329  2695  2695 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.338  1781  1781 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.338  1781  1781 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin, PID: 1781
05-25 02:13:08.338  1781  1781 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.349  2695  2897 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: [cxt] processing com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.FileApkIntentOperation for action com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.STAGE_MODULE_APKS
05-25 02:13:08.349  2695  2897 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 2695
05-25 02:13:08.349  2695  2897 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.349  2695  3238 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: [cxt] processing com.google.android.gms.common.analytics.CoreAnalyticsInitHandler for action com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.NEW_MODULE
05-25 02:13:08.349  2695  3238 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 2695
05-25 02:13:08.349  2695  3238 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.350  2695  3230 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: [cxt] processing com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.FileApkIntentOperation for action com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.LOG_LOAD_ATTEMPT
05-25 02:13:08.350  2695  3230 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 2695
05-25 02:13:08.350  2695  3230 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.354  2437  3285 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GCMWriter
05-25 02:13:08.354  2437  3285 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 2437
05-25 02:13:08.354  2437  3285 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.358  3307  3325 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-25 02:13:08.358  3307  3325 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gm, PID: 3307
05-25 02:13:08.358  3307  3325 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.420  2437  2437 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.420  2437  2437 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 2437
05-25 02:13:08.420  2437  2437 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.423  2437  2978 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[4]
05-25 02:13:08.423  2437  2978 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 2437
05-25 02:13:08.423  2437  2978 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.423  2437  3350 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FetchTask
05-25 02:13:08.423  2437  3350 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 2437
05-25 02:13:08.423  2437  3350 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.508  1868  1868 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.508  1868  1868 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.phone, PID: 1868
05-25 02:13:08.508  1868  1868 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.547  2993  2993 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.547  2993  2993 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.apps.messaging, PID: 2993
05-25 02:13:08.547  2993  2993 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.614  2437  3211 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: netscheduler-queue-handler
05-25 02:13:08.614  2437  3211 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 2437
05-25 02:13:08.614  2437  3211 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.630  2437  2981 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[6]
05-25 02:13:08.630  2437  2981 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 2437
05-25 02:13:08.630  2437  2981 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.734  3074  3074 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.734  3074  3074 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.apps.messaging:rcs, PID: 3074
05-25 02:13:08.734  3074  3074 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.739  2513  2513 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.739  2513  2513 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher, PID: 2513
05-25 02:13:08.739  2513  2513 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-25 02:13:08.741  1950  1950 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:13:08.741  1950  1950 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.setupwizard, PID: 1950
05-25 02:13:08.741  1950  1950 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a very old thread, but:

[anon:libc_malloc:c9d80000] - you are maybe out of RAM on the runner